# how to create a pointer to reflect.Value

Tags: go, reflection

I see many questions that appear to ask what I'm asking but I didn't see any actual response to the general question, just specific stuff.

I have reflect.Value of an int with a value of 64.

I have a slice that I got with reflection, that the type of the items in the slice is *int.

```
newSlice := reflect.Append(slice, currentRow.Convert(slice.Type().Elem()))
slice.Set(newSlice)
```

if I just run this, I get `panic: reflect.Value.Convert: value of type int cannot be converted to type *int`

I tried to run `currentRow.Interface()` but it returns an interface type pointer that cannot be added to the slice.

so how can I do that properly ?

I cannot know if it will be *int, or *string or anything else, I need it to be genneric

Comment: Is your goal to create a `[]*int` instead of a `[]int`?

Comment: @CeriseLimón - my goal is to convert int to *int in order to insert it to a []*int slice, all with reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the value to a variable:

```
v := reflect.New(currentRow.Type())
v.Elem().Set(currentRow)
```

Add the address of the variable to the slice:

```
newSlice := reflect.Append(slice, v)
slice.Set(newSlice)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `reflect.Value`, and if that value is addressable, that is, if `value.CanAddr()` returns true, then `value.Addr()` returns a `reflect.Value` that has a pointer to the value.

Comment: If it is not addressable, you cannot get a pointer to it. If you want to append this value to an []*int, and if you have a constant value like `1`, you have to assign it to a variable first.